# PHP 7.1 install solr.so fail, but PHP 7.0 is successful

Tags: php, ubuntu, solr

I get the following error during PHP Solr PECL Extension installation on version **7.1**:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20160303/solr.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/solr.so:
>   undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init in Unknown on line 0

Full trace:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/solr.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/solr.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.1.0-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.0-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

On version **7.0** everything installs correctly.

Comment: Have you recompiled the solr extension after upgrading to 7.1?

Comment: I use 'apt-get install php-solr' install php Extended，and print phpinfo ,php7.0 can search solr, but php7.1 cannot

Comment: @zhangzhiwei how have you installed php 7.1 - and how have you installed the `solr` extension for php 7.1? The error looks like you've just copied the extension, compiled for php 7.0, over to php 7.1 ...